# Do I need Permission for Acknowledgements or Reprinting Articles?

Tags: fiction, novel, legal

I can not recall the book, but one of Isaac Asimov's novels ends with an article on muon-catalyzed fusion. I remember that because it was so impressive to find out that such a thing was real.

I've also seen a few other authors acknowledge the origin of the ideas they are promoting in an acknowledgements section at the end of the book.

What is the right way to make acknowledgements or reposting articles?

For reposting articles, I'd think at a minimum that I need to ask the original publication for permission (and maybe the author).

What is the right to make acknowledgements? Should I write someone asking for their permission before including them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get permission from the copyright owner to republish.**

It's nice to ask the author too but contact whoever owns the copyright, which isn't always the original publisher, especially for an older work.  Republishing includes putting it on your blog or even posting to a mailing list, though that gets fudged (ignore "free use" footers as they're not legally legitimate).  You do not need permission to use it for an academic class (a real class).

**You don't need permission to acknowledge.**

If you're acknowledging a published work, you absolutely do not need get permission first.  Authors and publishers are generally delighted to have you read and reference them.  As long as you're not doing an acknowledgment in lieu of permission to reprint, you're good.

If you're using an unpublished work, you should check in with the author, to make sure s/he still wants it publicized.  And, if the work comes from family or friends, definitely ask.  Legally you're probably okay here, but it's ethically a good idea to check.